# Wordpress, all plugin updates, "Update Failed: Access denied."

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Working site. Every plugin:

1. Can be activated/deactivated.
2. Failed to update, reports "Update Failed: Access denied."

I checked directory permissions, and all seems OK to (a) other sites (b) hosted at the same place (1and1) where (c) the other sites do not have this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before, and the answer ended up being reinstalling wordpress. Specifically the wp-admin and wp-includes folders!

Comment: I check other resources, and they suggested recursive directory and file permission changes (kinda scary). The two shell commands (from the WP root) are:

find /path/to/base/dir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
find /path/to/base/dir -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +

Answer (score 1):

there is one solution that you can manually update plugins folder from project directory

Comment: thx @wpdevloper_j for your hint.  I am also facing this error - i have to check the logs for getting it fixed. Thanks for the clearing!